# Showing any metric space is a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

[image]

This is the question i've been given along with the solution i have written, however, could someone explain why showing $z \notin V$ shows any metric space is a Hausdorff space

Comment: The idea is to show if a point is in one of the open neighborhoods, it cannot be in the other. This shows the intersection of the open neighborhoods of $x,y$ is empty, satisfying the conditions of being Hausdorff.

Comment: Um, are you asking us to explain why _you_ have written the solution in the way you did? Wouldn't you be the person who knows that best?

Comment: yes please, i mainly got this solution from studying different sources online but don't fully understand why this is sufficient to show all metric spaces are Hausdorff